# Can Tensorflow be installed alongside Theano?

Tags: nvidia, tensorflow, theano, deep-learning

I'm trying to install tensorflow alongside Theano on a Nvidia Tesla K80. I'm working with Cuda 7.5 and following the instructions given [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md)
Theano by itself works well, but as soon as I install tensorflow from source code following the instructions OR using pip install, nvidia-smi as well as Theano stops working.

More specifically, nvidia-smi hangs indefinitely whereas Theano just refuses to run in GPU mode.

I'm also using the latest version of cudnn v4. 
Does Tensorflow have known issues with respect to causing nvidia-smi to hang and being non-compatible with Theano?

Comment: Simply installing TensorFlow shouldn't cause other software on your computer to stop working. However, *using* TensorFlow at the same time as Theano might not work because, by default, TensorFlow assumes it can use all of the RAM in your GPU. Are you running a TensorFlow program when you see either of these errors?

Comment: Hi. I have a K80 GPU which comes with 2 GPU cards. Even if TensorFlow programs are running on GPU0 , running Theano programs on GPU1 should be okay, right? 
The errors happen regardless of whether a tensorflow program is running. That is how I observed the error for the first time, but even after stopping all the programs and rebooting the system, nvidia-smi seems permanently 'damaged' in the sense that it hangs indefinitely. Same for 'import theano'. Hangs indefinitely.

Comment: TensorFlow is going to grab all RAM on all GPUs it finds so you may have trouble with Theano. Also if your 'nvidia-smi' hangs then probably nothing GPU-related will work. I ran into this problem once, and it was fixed by restarting computer.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow pick all the avaible GPU. So if you start it before Theano, Theano won't have any GPUs available by default. If you start Theano first, TensorFlow will segfault when it can't get the GPU Theano use.

To work around that, make the NVIDIA driver only show to TensorFlow the device that you want him to see with this environment variable:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python ...
```