# How to make tensorflow and theano share gpus simultaneously?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, theano

for some complicated reasons I use both tensorflow and theano in my python code, and I have 2 gpus which I want them to share, but as stated in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36720413/7801448) there is some problem, I want to know if there's some trick to achieve that, like specifying tensorflow to use only 1 gpu while theano using another?

for now I can only disable theano's gpu usage by `os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = 'device=cpu,floatX=float64'`, and let tensorflow use all

```py
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = 'device=cpu,floatX=float64'
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as ks
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this. However if you have multiple GPUs, you can force to run the code on GPU using the following trick:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    # Run the tensorflow code

import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    # Run the theano code
```

Hope this helps!